# How to replace static variables with scala available means in a base class

Tags: scala, static, companion-object

What I need:

```
trait Base {
  import scala.math.{Pi=>mPi, cos=>msoc, sin=>msin}
  static val Pi : Float = mPi.toFloat
  static def cos(phi : Float) : Float = mcos(phi).toFloat
  static def sin(phi : Float) : Float = msin(phi).toFloat
  // ...
  // some useful functions
}
// children use float defined pi, cos and sin without additional boilerplate
class Child1 extends Base
// ...
class Child2 extends Base
```

That obviously would not work. What I tried

```
trait Base {
  import Base._
  // some useful functions
}
object Base {
  // utility functions
  import scala.math.{Pi=>mPi, cos=>mcos, sin=>msin}
  val Pi : Float = mPi.toFloat
  def cos(phi : Float) : Float = mcos(phi).toFloat
  def sin(phi : Float) : Float = msin(phi).toFloat
}
class Child1 extends Base {
  // use sin and cos inside
}
```

And the compiler gives errors in `Child1` that it does nothing about functions `sin` and `cos`.

How can I define a static members in a base class that would be inherited by its descendants?

Comment: What about adding the import statement at the beginning of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you thinking in terms of static? All you need to do is create a method with no argument list that returns the `Float` forms of your constants.

For better or worse, as you've discovered, imports in a class or trait scope a not inherited.

```
package rrs.scribble

trait   FloatMath
{
  import scala.math.{Pi => mPi, cos => mcos, sin => msin}

  def Pi: Float = mPi.toFloat
  def cos(phi: Float): Float = mcos(phi).toFloat
  def sin(phi: Float): Float = msin(phi).toFloat
}

object  FM1
extends FloatMath
{
  val twoPi = 2.0f * Pi
}
```

In the REPL:

```
scala> import rrs.scribble.FM1._
import rrs.scribble.FM1._

scala> twoPi
res0: Float = 6.2831855

scala> cos(twoPi)
res1: Float = 1.0
```

As you see, the static types of `Pi`, `twoPi`, `cos`, etc. are all `Float`, not `Double`.

Comment: I may not replace val with a function def. As I've experimented with scala inheritance system, a I may use val instead of def, but vise versa would be denied by type system. So val and def are essentially different entities, and probably def is more expensive than val

Comment: Incorrect. If you use `val` to hold a constant, every instance will have a (redundant) copy while with a `def` it will be part of the bytecode and shared by all instances. Furthermore, access to `val` still goes through an accessor method. Either way, the JIT native code compilation is likely to make them identical at run time.

Answer (score 1):

How about choosing either mixing in a trait or importing members from an object?

And I think the latter is better.

```
trait MathUtils { 
  def cos(phi : Float) : Float = ...
}
class Child1 extends MathUtils { cos(1.0F) }
```

or

```
object MathUtils { 
  def cos(phi : Float) : Float = ...
}
class Child1 { 
  import MathUtils._
  cos(1.0F)
}
```

Comment: I'm using method #2 for now, but it bothers me, since children are really small and import statement stand out too much